# Ecmascript use of window.onerror

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to wrap my head around something I just read in "professional Javascript", by *Nicholas Zakas*: It gives the following code as an example:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, line){
alert(message);
return false;
};
```

and then says: "By returning false, this function effectively becomes a try-catch statement for the entire document, capturing all unhandled runtime errors. This event handler is the **last line of defense** against errors being reported by the browser.."

So my question is, will this piece of code prevent the execution of your script from stopping, with any error it encounters? or are there any errors that will still stop execution? thanks.

---

edit: maybe a better question would be, why is this not a good method for preventing a script from stopping its execution when it hits an error..

Comment: the code stops, but this callback fire.

Comment: doesn't the "try catch"like behavior cause it to not stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure something like a syntax error would be considered fatal whether or not the exception is ignored.

Using this is a bad idea, partly because there's already a perfectly adequate exception handling mechanism in the browser's error console, but mostly because if your site has errors then blasting them in your users' faces will not make them likely to return.

Comment: agreed, but maybe if you modify it to say console.log(...) instead of the alert?

Comment: mm, I see.. I guess I'm still trying to wrap my head around how error handling works.. Basically I'm wondering what's the best way to prevent an error from stopping the execution of your script.

Comment: @MattDerami The whole point of errors is that they shouldn't be there. Continuing despite errors could potentially have security implications.

Comment: kolink.. No I get that. The reason I ask is because I'm just starting out building cms sites with wordpress, and there are countless times where a client might say hit enter before inserting an image on a post, or a thousand other things.. So like it says in the post, this can be used as a last line of defense.. So I'm just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: Application logic errors should be dealt with where they present themselves, not in a single catch-all location. For example, the client hitting enter before inserting image on a post should be handled in the form's onsubmit handler.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple test shows that this is not the case (at least with Chrome):

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, line){
    alert(message);
    return false;
};
throw 'Catch this error';
```

No alerts, uncaught exception appears in console.

Comment: Yeah, I think `window.onerror` only fires some of the time, but I don't know in what circumstances :\